# why I can't create a new Date() from given string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I'm using moment.js to find a time in different timestamp.
I wrote a simple javascript:

```
$(function () {
    var timestamp = 1443556318; //GMT Tue, 29 Sep 2015 19:51:58 GMT
    var today2 = moment.unix(timestamp).tz('America/New_York').toString();
        today = new Date(today2);
        alert(today2);
        alert(today);

        var hh = today.getHours();
        alert(hh); //why it shows me 21 instead of 15?   
});
```

and seems like this line `today = new Date(today2);` does not work properly. 
Can you help me with that?

http://jsfiddle.net/b8o5cvdz/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because, you use the following constructor

```
new Date(dateString);
```

where the

> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format
>   recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC 2822
>   timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

If you want to all the possible constructors, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).